# Invalid parameters in SQLConnection

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql

I have a .NET application that connects to a database.

In my `web.config` file I have

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TFOUNDATION" 
         connectionString="Data Source=TAPOLCISQL01;Initial Catalog=TapolciFoundation;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=XXXX;Password=XXXXX" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Username and password removed.

In my code behind I open the connection like this

```
protected void grabData()
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT FirstName FROM CauseMarketers", new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TFOUNDATION"]));
}
```

The error I'm receiving is

> The best overload method match for "System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection.SQLConnection(string)" has some invalid arguments.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the `.ConnectionString` property on the config you fetch:

```
protected void grabData()
{
    // use the .ConnectionString property to get the connection string!
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TFOUNDATION"].ConnectionString;

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT FirstName FROM CauseMarketers", new SqlConnection(connStr));
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much. I had typically done connections to database by putting it in <appsettings>

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I open a database connection, I always get prompted to call `ToString()` on it.

Have you tried `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TFOUNDATION"].ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

Just removing "Persist Security Info=True;" may fix the issue. Please try.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to use 'persist security info' ?

> The ConnectionString is similar to an OLE DB connection string, but is not identical. Unlike OLE DB or ADO, the connection string that is returned is the same as the user-set ConnectionString, minus security information if the Persist Security Info value is set to false (default). The .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server does not persist or return the password in a connection string unless you set Persist Security Info to true.

Source: [MSDN Article about SqlConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx)

This website has everything you need to know about connection strings, and which one to use and how [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/), and this page is about the provider you're using [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/)

> Standard Security
>   Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
>   Password=myPassword;

So, try removing 'persist security info' and change 'initial catalog' to 'database'.